# how to set python IDLE's default python?

Tags: python, windows-7

I installed python 3.2 and later installed python 2.7. Somehow the IDLE, which I open it by right-click on python file -> Edit with IDLE, are using python 2.7 instead of python 3.2.

It seems that python 2.7 was set as default with IDLE. Even if I changed the PATH environment variable in windows advance setting back to python 3.2, the default python shell is still 2.7. I am sure that there was no more python 2.7 in the path.

Later I have to uninstall python 2.7 and reinstall python 3.2.

Comment: Each version of Python should come with it's own IDLE implementation. You have to change the default IDLE to open your scripts with. I'm not too familiar with windows, but I would assume that there is some key in the registry that contains the commands in the right-click menu. You probably have to edit the path in that key to point to IDLE 3.2.

Comment: I actually have both of them on my computer, both labeled `python idle`

Answer (score 1):

The IDLE context menu plug-in is registered when you install Python and points to the version of IDLE supplied with the Python installed. (IDLE itself has significant code changes between Python 2 and 3 because it's written in Python and the language changed a lot.) To change it, simply re-install the version of Python you wish the IDLE context menu to invoke.

Comment: But if I did that wouldn't all my Python 3 modules get deleted? Can I stop that?